# why is native c faster than java in android development

Tags: java, c, android-ndk, native-code

I've read some articles about Android NDK. Most of them claim Native C is faster than Java but they didn't explain the reasons. Could anybody explain and give sources why is Native C faster?

Comment: Well, what does it take to run Dalvik bytecode? What overhead(s) might this add?

Comment: C runs closer to the hardware and doesn't have things like subscript checking, string length checking, or garbage collection; these things tend to make C applications run faster than higher level languages like Java, Python, and Ruby

Comment: C should always be faster than java everywhere...

Comment: It really doesn't take much research. Just google for it and you'll find lots of information about the pros and cons of using virtual machines.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-level_programming_language, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-level_programming_language

Comment: Of course, there are other factors, like speed of development and maintainability...

Comment: On a PC significant resources can be thrown at the problem of optimising the code as efficiently as possible. Even so the HotSpot compiler comes in two flavours `client` which has shorter startup times and `server` which can be faster in the long run.  Many android devices are relatively limited hardware and/or power requirements so you can't expect a phone to spend as much time making the code run as efficiently as possible. What you can do in C is compile the code once on a PC and run it on an Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java has to be interpreted by a virtual machine while C communicates directly with the system. The thing is, since java has to be interpreted, you could say that it has to pass by a checkpoint when it does something while C has a direct pass. But that virtual machine has some advantages too. For instance, it allows the code to be runable on almost any system. In comparison the C is machine dependant.

Comment: Might want to read up on [the Dalvik JIT](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/dalvik-jit.html) and [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation). Thinking of Java as [strictly] "interpreted" makes it sound slow...

Comment: C is not machine-dependent unless written incorrectly. The output of a C compiler is what's machine-dependent.